# php search a string for 4 or more numbers with a decimal and format it to currency

Tags: php

I have an include that I'm pulling into a php page that's just a standard table with prices and whatnot.

E.g.

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hard Top</td>
    <td>17170.00</td>
    <td>5930.00</td>
    <td>20818.00</td>
    <td>2282.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hard Top XS</td>
    <td>20972.50</td>
    <td>7197.50</td>
    <td>25381.00</td>
    <td>2789.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is search through the include (I presume by putting it into a string first) then formatting all the numbers that are >= 4 characters long with a decimal point into currency.

so i would format '17170.00' as '£17,170.00' but I want to leave '90' alone as that's a title.

I know how to format into currency, that part's easy. But how do I search for clusters of numbers in a string that are >= 4 characters and have a decimal in the middle of them?

Would it use a regex (I've used them before but the intricacies still elude me) or would it be something simpler?

Comment: If '90' in this case is a title, why not make it one with a `<th>` tag; it makes it semantically relevant then and means you can have titles like 1000.10 (a very precise measurement in mms perhaps) as you can then only target `<td>` tags for data ... possibly also worth considering the NumberFormatter class : http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php

Comment: A good question. Because these external tables have been provided by someone else and I want to make it so I've formatted everything externally without touching the core files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$string = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.html');
$string = preg_replace('#<td>(\d{4,}\.\d{2})</td>#', '<td>£$1</td>', $string);
```

I put the `td`s in there to restrict to only numbers in table cells as you have shown.  You can remove these if not needed.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F97o6OH3CNP0R0Da)

Added an example with a callback to format the number.  Might want to look at `money_format` instead, but I'm headed to lunch:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('#<td>(\d{4,}\.\d{2})</td>#',
function($matches) { return '<td>£'.number_format($matches[1], 2).'</td>'; },
$string);
```

Comment: although this answer is perfectly correct... I just have this niggling feeling that the question is wrong.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Works perfectly. Quick modification: How would I add a comma if it's over 999 before the decimal? At the moment it says £17170.00, ideally I'd like it to say £17,170.00. Sorry if I'm being stupid and it's obvious!

Comment: It just seemed that the initial data structure is "wrong"; that there are better ways of doing it - but the OP states that they're 3rd party imported files that he doesn't want to touch ... which is fair enough - so this is a great answer for that imperfect situation ;)